# Why would CP11 notice of incorrect Child Tax Credit have an amount that isn't a multiple of $500

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-credit, children

I received a CP11 notice saying they changed the amount claimed as nonrefundable Child Tax Credit or credit for other dependents because I either didn't enter an amount or entered an incorrect amount based on the number of boxes checked on page 1 of return.

I don't understand that because I claimed 2 dependents everywhere. But what's really confusing me is that they changed the amount by $250.40 instead of $500 or $1000.

What could have happened to calculate such a seemingly odd number?

Comment: Was your income above the 'full amount' threshold?

Comment: @mkennedy If I'm understanding it correctly, no. Our joint income was under $200K

Comment: Which tax year is this for? Does the amount you are saying that they reduced your credit ($250.40) include penalties and interest?

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I didn't include the interest. I thought there wasn't a penalty either but just noticed there was

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica Totally off-topic but what is with the "Monica" stuff I keep seeing in people's user names?

Comment: @Kevin See [this meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/232449) and [this post by our money.SE mods](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2788/10997) for some history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this was for tax year 2021:

You said in a comment that your joint income was below $200,000. However, the first phaseout of the child tax credit begins at $150,000 for married filing jointly. After that point, your child tax credit gets reduced by $50 (per child) for each $1,000 your income is above $150,000, until your credit is reduced to $2,000 per child. For example, if you have one child between the ages of 6-17, your child tax credit would normally be $3,000, but if your joint income was $155,000, the credit would be reduced by $250 to $2,750.

See [this IRS FAQ on the calculation of the child tax credit](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/2021-child-tax-credit-and-advance-child-tax-credit-payments-topic-c-calculation-of-the-2021-child-tax-credit) for more details.

The amount of the tax credit is calculated on [Schedule 8812](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-schedule-8812-form-1040).

The amount you see on your CP11 notice probably also includes some penalties and interest that were also assessed as a result of your tax calculation mistake, which could be why the difference you are seeing is not a multiple of $50.

Comment: Thank.you very much. I think that explains it. I don't understand why TurboTax didn't calculate it correctly, but that's a question for another day